# I'm having a weird issue every time I try to use ' sudo apt-get install'. I can only describe it with a picture

Tags: apt, nano

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install` my terminal starts to install whatever I'm trying to install, then it goes into a weird state

[image]

If I exit the terminal and try to `sudo apt-get install` again, I get this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

When I restart my computer, and try to `apt-get install` I get this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then run `sudo apt-get install` again, I then go back to the original problem (see above).

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+X to exit nano and continue with installation? Does it happen with all packages you are trying to install?

Comment: Are you giving it a package name to install? ie: `sudo apt-get install packagename`?

Comment: yeah, it does happen to all packages I try to install @joshas

Comment: yeah, I give it a package name @heynnema

Comment: I just pressed ctrl x to exit nano and it the package continued installing. Thank you @joshas, what a simple solution; and I couldnt find ithis problem anywhere